# How does Kafka sends message to concrete user?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

System contains users entity.
Each user can get messages by type.

How to organise this in Kafka?
I know, I can create topic Messages and store message by key user-id but what if are million users? 
Million partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are a million users when using user-id as key, it will mean that they will be split among the partitions by `hash(user_id) % num_partition` when using the default partitioner, i.e. evenly distributed when your user-ids are not skewed. Choose the number of partitions that suits best for your use case though.

Answer (score 0):

By default Kafka will use a hash of the message key and round-robin the messages over the number of partitions. If you have a million unique key values and two partitions, each partition will get 500,000 keys. If you have ten partitions, each gets 100,000 keys, and so on.

Read more:

- http://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html
- https://medium.com/streamthoughts/understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies-and-how-to-write-your-own-custom-assignor-ebeda1fc06f3
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06iRM1Ghr1k&list=PL5T99fPsK7prvk569_RAbHuBXhEHLar4g&index=2&t=5s

Comment: Could you provide this on schema? I did not get about partitions, when I need to store messages for concrete users